# How to remove unwanted red border around (3 state) checked listbox items?

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, listboxitem

I've created a ListBox that has a three state CheckBox for each ListBox item, with a custom CheckBox images for each state.  The problem is that when items are set to this third (`null`) state there is an unwanted red border around the item, and I don't know why this appears or how to remove it.

Here is the style for the ListBox:

```
<Style x:Key="ThreeStateCheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <CheckBox Focusable="False" Foreground="{StaticResource textBrush}" 
                                      IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <CheckBox.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image x:Name="checkboxImage" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/CheckBoxUncheck_16x.png" Width="16"
                                                   Margin="0,0,2,0" />
                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Images/CheckBox_16x.png"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Images/CheckBoxExclude_16x.png"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </CheckBox.Template>
                                <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like this binding

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
                    Mode=TwoWay,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

is responsible for observed result, because `CheckBox.IsChecked` can be `True` | `False` | `null` (`Nullable<bool>`), when `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` is `bool`

if I set verbose trace info, using `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High`

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, 
                    Mode=TwoWay,
                    PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

I'm getting:

```
BindingExpression : GetValue at level 0 from ListBoxItem using DependencyProperty(IsSelected): 'False'
BindingExpression : TransferValue - got raw value 'False'
BindingExpression : TransferValue - using final value 'False'
BindingExpression : Update - got raw value 'True'
BindingExpression : Update - using final value 'True'
BindingExpression : SetValue at level 0 to ListBoxItem using DependencyProperty(IsSelected): 'True'
BindingExpression : GetValue at level 0 from ListBoxItem using DependencyProperty(IsSelected): 'True'
BindingExpression : TransferValue - got raw value 'True'
BindingExpression : TransferValue - using final value 'True'
BindingExpression : Update - got raw value <null>
BindingExpression : Update - using final value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
```

`null` results in {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue} and it is an error for bool IsSelected property

Red border around item is a default `Validation.ErrorTemplate`. You can disable it on CheckBox

```
<CheckBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" ...
```

note that CheckBox in undeterminate state (IsChecked=null) doesn't clear selection of ListBoxItem

Comment: It works perfectly with the above suggestions, thank you kindly.